# Removing Send Connector from Exchange 2010 How to Update MX Records

Tags: exchange, mx-record, connector

In the past we used a send connector to send to an organization we work with but now that is changing and I have removed the send connector.  The problem though is that the MX records do not seem to be updating to the next MX records.

If I do a MXLOOKUP internally it has the wrong information but if I do an MXlookup on mxtoolbox.com it has the correct information.

Any suggestions on updating the internal records?

Comment: Please provide nslookup command output.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internal DNS, it might be you have configured an "hardcoded" entry with an hardcoded MX record.

Comment: Checked that and I am not seeing anything in there for MX in the forward lookup zones

Comment: How did you check?  Can you edit the results into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like emails have started coming through just took some time.